# What does arbitrary mean in the following context?

Tags: general-topology

I recently encountered a theorem stating,
"The arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact".
What does arbitrary product mean in this context? Any product of compact spaces? If that is the case why not just say, "The product of compact spaces is compact"?

Comment: Probably the author wanted to emphasize the fact that no limitation exists in the family of compact spaces you make the product of. I agree that the wording is not felicitous.

Comment: It means any product, the arbitrary is used to emphasise that the fact is not restricted to products of finitely many or countably many factors.

Answer (score 2):

The "arbitrary" is there for emphasis and disambiguation. If one writes just "A product of compact spaces is compact", it could be that the reader misinterprets that as referring [only] to a product of two [or by iteration finitely many] compact spaces. Writing "An arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact" makes it clear that not only finite products are meant here, and that there is no restriction on the number of factors.